# Match on full filename in Textmate bundle fileTypes section

Tags: textmatebundles

I want to modify the existing [Textmate Groovy bundle](https://github.com/textmate/groovy.tmbundle) so that it can be used for my `Jenkinsfile` files.

In `Syntaxes/Groovy.tmLanguage`, there is the `fileTypes` section:

```
<key>fileTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>groovy</string>
    <string>gvy</string>
</array>
```

However, these are file extensions, not file names, as [the reference doc](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars) I've found says:

> `fileTypes` (line 2) — this is an array of file type extensions that the grammar should (by default) be used with.

How can I make the bundle match on full filename for my `Jenkinsfile`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that **full filenames are actually supported** in the `fileTypes` section, despite what the doc said (possibly because that doc is from version 1).  There's an example of a match on `Rakefile` [here](https://macromates.com/blog/2007/file-type-detection-rspec-rails/).

Therefore, I could just do this:

```
<array>
    <string>groovy</string>
    <string>gvy</string>
    <string>Jenkinsfile</string>
</array>
```

Comment: And in fact, someone has opened a PR to do just this: https://github.com/textmate/groovy.tmbundle/pull/18